# How to export UVMap to paint with external tools

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm searching all over for a way to paint my UVMap in external tool, in my case photoshop, and them load it back to the mesh in render.

The problem is I want to use that blender export feature that creates a basic surface in the uvmap so it would be easy to identify the parts and paint in photoshop.

that this feature just exists in blender render as far as I searched.

any idea how to do that in cycles render?

I hope I was clear, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you unwrap your object. Use **Export UV layout** in the UV/Image_Editor

[image]

Then choose the format in which to export your image and the size you want:

[image]

Create your texture in Photoshop:

[image]